# jQuery DataTable - How to do pagination with server-side processing?

Tags: datatables

I want to use DataTables to show data to a user.
I read the document about "[Server-side processing"](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html), but 
I don't know PHP, so I can't figure out what has happened.

How client-side code sends the data to server-side script?
And how to let server-side script know how many records should be returned?

Comment: There is simple datatable server side in php  example [here](http://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/)

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the [Server-side processing](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side) chapter in the DataTables manual. The `length` parameter determines how many records are requested and `start` parameter determines first record index (zero-based).

Below is an excerpt from the manual:

> `start`
>
> Paging first record indicator. This is the start point in the current
>   data set (`0` index based - i.e. `0` is the first record).
>
> `length`
>
> Number of records that the table can display in the current draw. It
>   is expected that the number of records returned will be equal to this
>   number, unless the server has fewer records to return. Note that this
>   can be `-1` to indicate that all records should be returned (although
>   that negates any benefits of server-side processing!)

Comment: Yes ,Thank you ,I see those parameters that send to the server.

Comment: How do you set the parameter? I don't see any description which parameter I need to put these options in.